# Obtain arc points in latitude longitude system

Tags: geometry, geodesy

I have an arc of circumference defined by three points, center, start point, and end point; and I want to obtain several points of the arc.

With the parametric equations [proposed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779414/2d-parametric-equation-for-an-arc-between-two-points-with-a-start-angle) it seems not difficult to do.
The problem is that my points are defined by latitude and longitude, not x and y coordinates.

Is there any quick way to obtain latitude and longitude of points of the arc, without having to go the hard way (WGS84 conversions etc)?

I have a function based in [Vincenty inverse formulae](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiP_sSY84vXAhWD6xQKHbftDaMQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FVincenty%2527s_formulae&usg=AOvVaw1MeRLxBD3IVb9f7VmBeG3e) to obtain distance (in NM) and azimuth angle between these points if it can help.